# Desktop PC doesn't switch on, power cuts

Tags: windows, power-supply, hardware-failure, power, desktop-computer

Today I have quite a big problem with my HP Pavillon Desktop pre-built computer.

### So, what happens?

Well, when I press the power button, nothing happens. There's a led light on the back of the computer to indicate when the pc is receiving power, when I press the switch on button, the led just turns off and the pc is cut off it's power.

### What have I tried

I've tried a few things:

- I've tried changing the plug.
- The power cable.
- Opening up the computer to see if everything's in place and order.
- Power testing the plugs of my house to see if they're correctly delivering the good amount of power to my devices.

Didn't have much luck yet.

### Backstory

A while back, when I powered on my pc, it would suddenly cut... And then turn back on and then cut and turn back on... 3 or 4 times before the pc finally turns on. Once it's switched on, everything was fine, no files corrupted, no weird screen things, no slow down, it just worked fine.
It did this for a few months when I switched on the computer until one day, it just didn't switch on, like at all.

### More context

The problem/good thing is that a week ago after moving around the cable and keeping on trying to power on the pc, it actually powered on after months.
Once it was on well, it worked fine. Everything was going normal and everything was there where I left it.
After 25 minutes of fooling around on netflix, the power cut again and I haven't been able to switch it on since.

One of the big problems is that my family wants to buy a new computer, but we aren't rich and that would affect a bit the family, we could pay for a few months of rent for my brother for the amount a new pc costs.
I think it's probably just a problem with the PSU or the power outlet or something since the pc seems to work fine when it's finally switched on.
Perhaps, buying a new $20 pc part could spare us the $300+ price tag of a new PC.

**here's a video of the pc**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUI8fsHcSvE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This really does sound like the PSU; the symptoms are consistent with what my organization has seen with a large number of Dell computers (and I've seen at home with my old Gateway). That's what I'd look to first, anyway.

Comment: I have had very similar issue. You have to change mainboard.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yeah, I'm sorry to ask this but I'm not really a tech savy person, could I buy any PSU, I mean if I do a quick search on amazon, I can find a few but I don't know if they would fit correctly in the case. Also, because it's a prebuilt computer that isn't that powerful, what kind of voltage should I go for? Would 350W do the job or do I need more?

Comment: You should check the specifications for the model of computer you have, and get one that matches - or is of higher power. Most PSUs are more-or-less standard, but some brands - Compaq (now part of HP) used to be one such - deliberately chose non-standard form factors to lock you in to their (more expensive) replacement parts. I don't recall whether the Pavilion line was borged from Compaq or was an HP original line.